# Contact Angle Hysteresis

Tags: surface-chemistry

When solid surface is wetted and dewetted with some liquid, contact angle measured will not be the same. I am not sure what does process of wetting or dewetting have to do with contact angle or why should we get different values?

I understand that surface roughness, inhomogenity and solutes in liquid can affect contact angle, but what does it have to do with wetting or dewetting?

Comment: What is dewetting ? Is it drying ?

Comment: Yes, it is a process where contact area between solid and liquid is decreased while in wetting is increased.

Comment: And what is "In wetting" ?

Comment: Is "wetting" the advancing drop, while dewetting is retreating? Hysteresis is an observation that something goes differently one way from the way it goes back. Dewetting, i.e., retreating, is really retreating from a different surface (because it is totally wetted) than advancing over a totally dry surface.

Comment: Yes, wetting is increase of area of contact between liquid and solid by adding more liquid to liquid drop on solid surface while dewetting is reverse. What you said might be correct.

Comment: I believe recently wetted surface changes surface tension s-l and s-g, leading to different angle for gamma1 = gamma1 + gamma3 . cos alfa